# Form Library templates in SP 2007

Tags: 2007, infopath, forms-library

I want to create a form library template that's available for all site collections in my SP 2007 farm.  How do I go about doing that?  My understanding is that when I save a form library as a template, its only available within my site collection.  How can I get my form library template recognized at the farm level?

Comment: do you want the entire library as a template, or just the forms in the library?

Comment: the entire library, the folders, the forms, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking that the only way to do this would probably be to use a feature to deploy the library structure, however, I think you will also have to deploy the forms through Central Administration as administrator approved forms. You should be able to tie it all together in the feature and deploy it and activate it on the different sites.

Comment: can I do this more gracefully in SP 2010?